# Basic Question: How to allow users in the same workspace to install my app?

Tags: oauth, slack, slack-api

I have a small app up and running for myself. It's an app homepage with buttons that shoot requests out to our hosted app, which returns modal payloads. It works perfectly for me.

When I began development I had to ask that the app be installed by our admin.

When other users in the same workspace attempt to install it they're greeted with "This is still a work in progress" instead of the app homepage.

I don't wish to distribute the app beyond my current workspace so I don't think I need to implement the o-auth flow. Any hints? I'm sure I'm missing something small.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using a Home surface. To use app home surface you have to display it for each individual user, not a single time for the app, as I suspected.

When the user clicks on the app home page, it triggers an event that sends a payload to the URL you specify in the app's event subscription settings. You have to respond to slack api's `/views.publish` endpoint with a payload that defines the home appearance for that particular user. The user id is in the initial request payload.